# matching password from client with password in AD

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

the code I have below works, but it doesn't use the password that is passed from the client.  After I find the correct user in the AD, is there a way to match the password that is passed from the client with the password in the AD?

Thanks!

```
 Public Class FordLoginController
    Inherits ApiController
    Public Class StoreCredentials
        Public Property UsernameAX As String

        Public Property PasswordAX As String
    End Class

   Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal creds As StoreCredentials) As HttpResponseMessage
        Dim username As String = creds.UsernameAX
        Dim password As String = creds.PasswordAX

        Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ford", "dc=biz,dc=ford,dc=com")
        Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username)
        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage
        If user IsNot Nothing Then
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found)
            response.Headers.Location = New Uri("/loginAndContinue/login.aspx")
            Return response
        End If
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        Return response
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: `but it doesn't use the password that is passed from the client` and then you said `is there a way to match the password that is passed from the client with the password in the AD`, this is confusing and does not make any sense. ***if you don't use the password from the client, how can you match it against the one from AD***? Please clarify on what you mean.

Comment: @Codexer I mean I want to use the password that is passed, but I can't figure out how to match it with the password in the AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From VBForums

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?352349-Validate-Login-against-Active-Directory

```
Private Function ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(ByVal Domain As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
        Dim Success As Boolean = False
        Dim Entry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & Domain, Username, Password)
        Dim Searcher As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(Entry)
        Searcher.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.OneLevel
        Try
            Dim Results As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult = Searcher.FindOne
            Success = Not (Results Is Nothing)
        Catch
            Success = False
        End Try
        Return Success
    End Function
```

usage

```
If ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin("VBForums", "Woof", "Mouse") Then
   'do something
End If
```